# set $_POST value when radio button is selected

Tags: php, html

I have a page with some radio buttons and form. When I select one radio button I need its id to be set to $_POST['id'] varible so when I submit the form I can check which radio button was selected and act accordingly. I know I can't do it directly so tried using

```
onclick="document.getElementById("id").value="'.$row['id'].'"
```

on radio button but it didn't work.

```
$d="select * from {$_c['dbprefix']}card where active='1' order by s_sent desc, s_order asc limit 0,{$_c['filtr']['step']}";
$r=mysql_query($d);
if (mysql_num_rows($r)>0) {

echo '<div class="cards">';
echo '<form method="POST">';
$i=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)):

echo '<div class="item">';
echo '<input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="radio" name="id" class="detail">'.$_l['detailtitle'].'</input>';
echo '<label for="'.$row['id'].'" class="itemin" style="height:'.$_c['card']['sy'].'px"><img src="pub/cards/'.$row['id'].'s.jpg" /></lable>';
echo '</div>';

$i++;
if ($i%3==0) echo '<div class="cl-left"></div>';

endwhile;

echo '<div class="cl-left"></div>';
echo '</div>';
    }
?>



<div class="dvasl">

<div class="sl1">

<fieldset>
<legend>Saatja andmed</legend>
<table class="info">
<colgroup><col width="12%"><col></colgroup>
<tr>
<th>Nimi:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="item[from_name]" value="<?php echo $ap['set']['from_name']; ?>" class="inpedit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Email:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="item[from_email]" value="<?php echo $ap['set']['from_email']; ?>" class="inpedit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Saaja andmed</legend>
<table class="info">
<colgroup><col width="12%"><col></colgroup>
<tr>
<th>Nimi:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="item[to_name]" value="<?php echo $ap['set']['to_name']; ?>" class="inpedit"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Email:</th>
<td><input type="text" name="item[to_email]" value="<?php echo $ap['set']['to_email']; ?>" class="inpedit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

</div>
<div class="sl2">

<fieldset>
<legend>E-kaardi tekst</legend>
<table class="info">
<tr>
<td><textarea name="item[text]" cols="20" rows="8" class="inpedit2"></textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>

</div>

<div class="cl-left"></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
<div class="t2"><input type="submit" value="Vaata kaardi eelvaadet" name="button[nahled]" class="unbutt1"></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $ap['card']['id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="itemadd">
</form>

<?php
$k=floor(($i-1)/3);
if ($k<2) echo '<div class="spacer-'.(2-$k).'"></div>';

?>
```

Comment: thats ok use name attribute  for the button.

Comment: what you mean by that?

Comment: as u asked that  you want to check which radio button was selected.as you are using <form> so i told you to give a name attribute in the radio button so in the backend u will know by the value of that name attribute which radio button was selected.i dont know why u are using javascript for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you can use a hidden field in the form and update its value with the id of the selected radio button and when the form will be posted you can get its value and more over this after once you changed the value of the hidden field you can access it with javascript also with id attibute and can get it in the post by name attribute

add a hidden field named

```
<input type="hidden" id="checked_radio" name="checked_radio" value="" />
```

and then change the value with javascript on click of button

```
<input type="radio" id="foo" name="foo" onclick="document.getElementById('checked_radio').value=this.value;" />
```

Comment: nice answer.this is what i am saying in the comment @martinv

Comment: Happy to help you martinv you can get the value in the post by $_POST['checked_radio'] 

You can pass comma separated string also in hidden if you want to 
pass multiple things or ids at a time
Thanks for the support Rishabh

Answer (score 1):

The value of the selected radio button gets posted, and the `name` is used to group radio buttons together. (Only one radio button with the specified `name` can be selected.) Instead of trying to post the value of the `id` attribute you should add a `value` attribute and set that. You could set it to the same value as the `id` attribute, or remove the `id` attribute completely.

Answer (score 0):

> When I select one radio button I need its id to be set to `$_POST['id']` variable

You are changing the value, not the id, to change the id use:

```
onclick="document.getElementById("id").id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>";
```

Anyway, I think you should use the `name` attribute for this.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
echo '<input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="radio" name="id" class="detail">'.$_l['detailtitle'].'</input>';
```

to

```
echo '<input id="'.$row['id'].'" type="radio" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="id" class="detail">'.$_l['detailtitle'].'</input>';
```

when your form submit,you will get the selected id as `$_POST['id']`